# Can ImageMagick find a scaled down match of a large image?

Tags: imagemagick, image-comparison

I'm working on a project where we need to match original hi-resolution photos to their scaled down counterparts.  For example the original may be 2000px x 2000px, and the scaled down version might be 500px x 500px.

In researching how to do this I've found mention that ImageMagick's `compare` operation can be used to compare larger and smaller images, but that it behaves as though the smaller image has been cropped from the larger--and as a result it performs a very intensive scan (http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=16781#p61937).

Is there an option or flag that I can use to indicate that I only want a match if the smaller image has been scaled (not cropped) from the larger image?

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily scale the larger image down to the size of the smaller image and then compare the resized version to the thumbnails, as described by Marc Maurice on his [blog](http://positon.org/compare-diff-between-two-images).

```
convert bigimage.png -resize 500x500 MIFF:- | \
compare - -metric AE -fuzz '10%' smallimage.png null:
```

Because the resize algorithm is probably different from the original resize algorithm, this will introduce differences, but if the smaller images are only scaled and not changed otherwise, the similarities should be sufficient to do the matching. You'll have to find a suitable metric and threshold though.

If you don't now the thumbnail sizes or if they differ, you may want to downsize both images to a safe size below the minimum of all thumbnail sizes or you grab the thumbnail sizes with

```
identify -format "%w,%h" smallimage.png
```